# Why do control keys and arrow keys not work in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I use `MobaXterm` to control `linux` server remotely from my `windows` desktop. I use `Linux` and `pycharm` 2019.3 in the `linux` server for nearly one whole year. During the past year I can not use control keys in pycharm. To be specific, when I press arrow `left`, endless number `4` will be inserted in pycharm until I type a normal character from `a` to `z`. Similary, when I press arrow `right`, `up`, and `down`, endless `6`, `8`, and `2` will be inserted. Furthermore, when I press `insert`, `delete`,`home`, `end`, `page up`, and `page down`, endless number `0`,`.`,`7`,`1`,`9`, and `3` will be inserted into pycharm editor area until I press `backspace` or a normal character.

I tried to upgrade my pycharm from 2019.3 to 2020.2, but the same issue still exist.

I can not `delete` any thing, I have to use `backspace` to replace `delete`, it is awful。

I have been suffering the problem for one year. Please help me!

-----update------
I also found that when I disable the number lock, I can still type normal number using numeric keypad. Very weird.

-----update2-----
I found when I open the pycharm and just press control keys, everything goes well. But once I press a normal character (like a-z), this will trigger the issue, after that, control keys will not work normally.

-----update3-----
I uninstalled pycharm completely, and install it again. the issue still exist.
I restored default setting, the issue still exist.

-----update4----- This issue is related to: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150932
and
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206345169-Scrolling-with-keys-on-numeric-keypad-with-num-lock-off?input_string=Using%20Numeric%20Keypad%20Arrow%20Keys%20in%20CLion

-----update5----- This issue only exist in pycharm. Everything works correctly outside pycharm.

Comment: can you be more specific? endless number mean even if you press one time?

Comment: @deadshot Correctly

Comment: are you using a laptop? Those are the function of each key when the numeric lock is disabled

Comment: @RamónMárquez No, I use desktop and I have tried to use a new keyboard, the same issue still exist.

Comment: did you try clean & fresh installation?

Comment: @deadshot No, Can you tell me how to clean & fresh installation?

Comment: Check your keyboard function. Some keyboard have numpad key enable disable using Fn button and then F12 etc

Answer (score 1):

**I know why! How to fix PyCharm keyboard keymap numpad left, right, up & down Ctrl BUGs**

PyCharm latest version 2021.2 and many previous versions have 3 types of bugs in Keymap usually with larger keyboards with numpads on the right. (There are more bugs/Trojans in plug-in specific keymaps, that may already use or have conflicting uses of key+mouse+key combinations.)

First to fix the bug (eg missing numpad "left" arrow), open pycharm:

1. (optional) Update pycharm+its plug-ins and restart.
2. (optional) Running out of disk space? Delete **ONLY the older backup PyCharmCE??? directories** that do not match your
   [ Help --> About --> Version ] value.  Those configuration directories under Linux are **~/.cache/JetBrains/**. Obviously do not delete the current PyCharmCE??? version.  Windows has a similar set, I think.  The bug here is the .cache/JetBrains directories are HUGE, and pycharm update fails to delete the oldest versions 3 versions back!
3. Go to the editors main Keymap:  **Ctrl+Alt+s --> Keymap --> Editor Actions** and find the keystrokes that offend you, in my case "up" "down" "left" and "right" which are PyChuggyBuggeyWuggy dead unresponsive keys on the numpad.
4. Strange you will find "up" "down" "left" and "right" already coded into that list. All you do is add the keystroke of interest for each, even if it already looks good, IT IS NOT!
5. Each action in the Keymap list can have one or more keystrokes. Do not delete the existing keystroke, you will be adding your new one.
6. **Double click on the chosen key in that very long Keymap list eg "left" --> "Add keyboard shortcut"** (Confusingly  it already says "Left" ignore that, it means non-numpad left, it is a bug).
7. **JUST PRESS YOUR OWN LEFT arrow key (on the numpad) on the keyboard.** then press **OK.**   A new left appears, it looks the same but is not ... BUG!
8. Press **Apply --> OK.** It just added ANOTHER Left.  That is actually a different Left!  (That is a **BUG** and it should say "numpad left").  Test your changes.

For ANY other keystroke or mouse+key combo you can do the same thing, pycharm
may not record the "name" of the action correctly, but it will remember the combo for correct use against each list under:   **Ctrl+Alt+s --> Keymap --> Editor Actions**

- **MAJOR BUG2**  PyCharm SECURITY FLAW.  Pycharm repeadedly phones home along with PlugIn violating security at least 160 times a day!  Not
  asking your permission. The atom editor and sublime do the same, do
  not tolerate that, BLOCK THEM with the firewall.
- **MAJOR BUG3**  PyCharm SECURITY FLAW.  Plugins have the ability to intercept any and every keystroke and use the Keymap.
  Many of the plug-ins are *"builtin"* and others are optional.  They can be updated with fake versions that are trojan horses that capture
  keystrokes. I do not see any way of verifying plug-ins, but I do see them violating security and phoning home information without your permission.